# Get Primefaces EventBus from another servlet

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces Websocket functionality; it's implemented using the Atmosphere framework.

I've two servlet defined in my webapp: the first one is for the frontend (there I'm using Primefaces and websocket functionalities), the second one is for API functionality (there I'm using Jersey and JAXRS feature).

What I need to do is: when a request is posted to a resource (using the API servlet), I need to send a message to all connected client using websockets.

On the second servlet, inside the method that intercepts post requests, I've tried with this solution:

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("subscriber/*", "This message is for all connected clients, through websockets");
```

It doesn't work, seems that the `EventBus` instance provider by `EventBusFactory`, is different from which one where all users are connected. The message is not broadcasted.

How is it possible?

If I try to broadcast a message from the first servlet, the same where clients are using websockets, all works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
Simply use

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("subscriber/*", "This message is for all connected clients, through websockets");
```

on the second servlet and `EventBus` will be resolved.
I've committed a syntax error, so the second servlet didn't resolve the `EventBus` properly.

So, be careful on write the right subscriber topic, in my case `"subscriber/*"`, in order to intercept all the endpoints created in the third-party servlet.